# When we change the probability measure, how does E[Z]=1 guarantee the new measure is legitimate?

Tags: measure-theory

I've read this in a lecture note but failed to understand it:

> Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ and a random
>   variable $Z$ satisfying the following conditions: $E^P(Z)=1$ and
>   $P(Z>0)=1$. Then we can construct a new probability measure by
>   defining $Q(A)=E^P(1_AZ)$ for all $A\in \mathscr{F}$. The first
>   condition on $Z$ makes $Q$ a probability measure, and the second makes
>   $P$ and $Q$ equivalent.

I can understand why they are equivalent under the second condition. But for the first one, since $Q(A)=E^P(1_AZ)=P(A)\times Z$ for all $A\in \mathscr{F}$, if we want Q to be a legitimate measure, it seems that all we need is $Q(\Omega)=P(\Omega)\times Z=Z=1$. Why do we need its expectation to be 1?

It makes perfect sense to me if $Q(A)$ is defined on $\Omega$, in which case I know how the expectation works, but probability measure is defined on $\sigma$-algebra. So I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why you write $E^P(1_A Z) = P(A) \times Z$. The left hand site is a number, but the right hand side is a (Cartesian?) product of a number and a function.

Second, we need the expectation to be 1 for $Q$ to be **probability** measure -- measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$ is probability measure precisely when $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1.$